# Can Fusion 360 optimize topology using only struts and triangles?

Tags: 3d-models, fusion360

I want to make a light titanium part which will be very visible and 3D printed. Can I force Fusion to use only struts like this?

[image: F1 brake pedals]

I realize it will limit the performance but in this application aesthetics are important.

Comment: Reopening, as this seems to be a 3D printing related question (and the third vote was by accident). Staker, even though it's not particularly relevant to your question, just out of interest how do you intend to print with titanium (which process)? Could you [edit] the question and add that please?

Comment: Even though your question *seems* to be related to 3D printing, you may get a better response asking on SE.Engineering, they have a lot of [Fusion 360 questions](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=fusion+360). Maybe delete this question and post it there (please don't cross-post)?